# Multiple date entries

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es

Here is some images for the intents and entites

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am collecting dates from users to se for creating google calendar events but as soon as I add the code for the second date even if it is not in use it fails to work for any of both dates
it gives this error in firebase:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
>       at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:38:68)
>       at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:37:41)
>       at /worker/worker.js:783:7
>       at /worker/worker.js:766:11
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)

This is my code

```
   function makeAppointment2 (agent) {
   const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('+')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
   const dateTimeEnd = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart).setHours(dateTimeStart.getHours() + 1));
   const dateTimeStart2 = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date2.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time2.split('T')[1].split('+')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
   const dateTimeEnd2 = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart2).setHours(dateTimeStart2.getHours() + 1));
   const appointmentTimeString = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString(
     'en-US',
     { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone }
   );
   const appointmentTimeString2 = dateTimeStart2.toLocaleString(
     'en-US',
     { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone }
   );
   return createCalendarEvent2(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, name, location, dateTimeStart2, dateTimeEnd2).then(() => {
     agent.add(`Great Mr/Mrs ${name}, your appointment has been scheduled on ${appointmentTimeString} & ${appointmentTimeString2}!.`);
     agent.add(`${response2}`);
   }).catch(() => {
     agent.add(`I'm sorry Mr/Mrs ${name}, there are no slots available for ${appointmentTimeString} Please choose another date.`);
   });
 function createCalendarEvent2 (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_name, location, dateTimeStart2, dateTimeEnd2) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    calendar.events.list({
      auth: serviceAccountAuth,
      calendarId: calendarId,
      timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
      timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
    }, (err, calendarResponse) => {

      if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
      } else {

        calendar.events.insert({ auth: serviceAccountAuth,
          calendarId: calendarId,
          resource: {
   'summary': appointment_name + "1st" ,
   'description': location,
   'start': {
     'dateTime': dateTimeStart,
   },
   'end': {
     'dateTime': dateTimeEnd,
   },
 } ,
        }, (err, event) => {
          err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
        }
        );
      }
    });
    calendar.events.list({
      auth: serviceAccountAuth,
      calendarId: calendarId,
      timeMin: dateTimeStart2.toISOString(),
      timeMax: dateTimeEnd2.toISOString()
    }, (err, calendarResponse) => {

      if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
        reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
      } else {

        calendar.events.insert({ auth: serviceAccountAuth,
          calendarId: calendarId,
          resource: {
   'summary': appointment_name + "2nd" ,
   'description': location,
   'start': {
     'dateTime': dateTimeStart2,
   },
   'end': {
     'dateTime': dateTimeEnd2,
   },
  } ,
        }, (err, event) => {
          err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
        }
        );
      }
    });

  });
```

Comment: Can u provide screenshots of intents and entities you r using?

Comment: I can add your email to the project

Comment: Is this code being called for the `appointment` intent handler or the `appointment2` intent handler? (For that matter, how are you setting up the handlers?)

Comment: this is a universal constants that i wanted to use later to call each one individually like i have the date1 and date2 so down i made intent appointment 2 if called it takes the parameter date2 and date1 and creates 2 events and same for appointment  but i will try the suugests and make it inside the functions and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest extracting parameters like this in your fulfillment:

```
 function botHandler(agent) {
        let state = agent.parameters["stateName"];
        let uState = state.toUpperCase();
        let answer = "So you live in " + uState + "?";

        agent.add(answer);
    }
```

And you can check if the parameter is present this way:

```
if (agent.parameters["stateName"]) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

I think it crashed because there were no intents present.

Comment: This suggestion worked well but now I am stuck with the function to create the events it doesnt seem to work any thoughts?

Comment: You should ask a new question for that sir!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56702126/i-want-to-create-multiplle-event-sat-once-using-javascript-from-a-dialogflow-bot

Comment: I'm afraid I have no experience with Google Calendar API.. I'm sorry